# How to enforce a prototype scope of Spring beans

Tags: java, spring, scope, javabeans

I have a stateful Spring bean. How can I enforce its usage scope to prototype in my application?

How can I prevent another developper on my project of injecting this bean with the singleton scope?

I know you can configure scope either via annotation or via the xml configuration. Of what I have seen, when using Spring 3, the scope configured by annotation gets overriden by the scope defined manually in the xml. How can I enforce my scope, thru configuration or programatically, so my bean will never be used as a singleton?

I thought about inspecting the bean scope on the startup of the application, but it doesn't sound like an elegant solution.

Comment: The people you're trying to 'protect' yourself against are the same people who wouldn't think twice about just going to the bean definition and changing it if they thought they wanted a singleton anyway.  There are way higher priority things than trying to protect your code from your peers malfeasance.

Comment: That's why I thought about a test approach on the startup of the app... but I'm not certain it would be a good solution. I know you shouldn't be too defensive, but my issue is that using a bad scope on this bean works, until you run out of memory. So it's hard to spot, and it might happen again. Peer reviewing every line of code might prevent it, but we don't have the man-power nor management will to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not elegant, but AFAIK this is the only way to achieve what you are looking for

```
public class MyStatefulBean implements InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware, BeanNameAware {

    private String myName;

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String s) {
        this.myName = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if(this.context.isSingleton(this.myName))
            throw new RuntimeException("Bean CANNOT be singleton");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that elegance can sometimes be an afterthought, when a critical part of the code-base must be protected against misuse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Document it?  There's no way for it to know if someone is keeping a reference to the bean and reusing it or sharing it across threads when they should have been using `getBean()` to get the prototype.

Spring cannot stop your peers from writing code that is simply incorrect, which is all that such a usage would be.

Comment: Fair enough, but can Spring stop my peers from overriding the configuration of the scope of a bean? (for the record, this is documented but some goof didn't read it and we had a memory leak caused by this in production)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on the API user doing what's expected of them, expose the bean via a factory.

Comment: A good old factory will do, but when using the Spring ServiceLocatorFactoryBean, I run the risk of having my configuration overriden anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: @sebul How would that override your configuration?

Comment: It would not override it, but it would be overridable in another Spring configuration importing the first one. Actually, what I would prefer, is that the scope defined by annotation would have the priority over the scope defined in the xml. Otherwise, in an app where Spring is literally overused, the danger of having the scope overriden by xml config is high. Especially when there are multiple levels of Spring configuration files.